# Linux diary program

Tags: linux, terminal

Is there a diary program for Linux that runs in the terminal?

Comment: `$EDITOR ~/diary.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If you want an appointment diary, there is the venerable `calendar` program (See `man calendar`)

Comment: +1 - Very nice. At first I thought you were referring to `cal`. I'd never seen `calendar` before. Some lovely entries in there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jrnl](http://jrnl.sh/) - The Command Line Journal that is written in python.